# SignalR web applications multiple Working processes in IIS 7.5 and 8

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, iis-7.5, iis-8

In my company we have many web applications on a web server. Recently we developed a Chat module to this applications using SignalR. But a strange problem occured on these applications. In time this apps becomes unreachable. Recycleing does not solve. When i try to restart application pools it stops an never starts again. I had create a new app pool and delete the old one. And some time later the problem recurs.

Then i noticed that these application pools have several working processes which have the state of "Closing" and one "Running". What can be the problem? It is about SignalR I know, becouse this problem occurs only the applications which i use SignalR and we have about fifty apps on the server in total and only four of them have signalR on it.

[screenshot of stopped process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdpjH.png)

Please help..

Comment: really? nobody's know anything about this? this cannot be happening only me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

months after i decided to answer my own question. i think it's about windows and iis version. i set up a windows 2012 machine and new version iis on it and on this new server this problem not occured.